What are the downsides for using Werkzeug with Flask for production with the flag `allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True`
I have written a script in Python using Flask for displaying my Raspberry Pi camera feed on a webpage and when I try and serve it for use on the Pi I get a crash with the error RuntimeError: The Werkzeug web server is not designed to run in production. Pass allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True to the run() method to disable this implying i shouldn't use the default serving method and should use something like gunicorn. Im just curious if there is a problem with running a production application with the  allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True flag.
I tried setting up gunicorn but it doesnt work probably due to it spinning up multiple instances of the camera and attempting to run many at once when the camera supports only one connection.

Are you using flask-socketio? This might be the issue. Usually the message you described should just be a warning and should not crash the app.

Please show us how you run the server.
